# Binding WPF DatagridCell to the source

Tags: wpf, binding, controltemplate

My original datagrid does have a few columns wherein the bound value is  bool.[By default this would show up as check boxes]

I have defined a cell template and could create

I would like to use a common datagrid controltemplate for this, like the one defined below.
However it doews not bring in the binding value - it shows up blank.

Could someone help spot me on what I am doing wrong?

```
    <Style x:Key="dgCellBool" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse.Height>10</Ellipse.Height>
                            <Ellipse.Width>10</Ellipse.Width>
                            <Ellipse.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Binding}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Binding}"  Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Ellipse.Style>   
                        </Ellipse>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind Binding property of DataGridCell but DataGridCell dont have any Binding property. Yoy should set Path=Column.Binding. DataGridCell has Column property which further has Binding Property.

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Column.Binding}"
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Hello ethicallogics, I have tried what you have suggested however it draws a blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `ContentPresenter` to present the content and make sure you add the `Border` that you will lose from the original `Template`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

UPDATE >>>

If you want your `Ellipse` instead of a `Border`, just add it back in with a `Grid`... `Ellipse` objects cannot have any content:

```
<Style x:Key="dgCellBool" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10">
                        <Ellipse.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={
RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Binding}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Ellipse.Style>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hiya Sheridan, Ok if I do add a ContentPresenter where would I apply the data triggers?